# Does any version of SQL allow this kind of join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So this is the only example of outer joins that we've gotten all year, and needless to say, it's wrong. I know full well that this command doesn't run on MySQL, so my question is, does this command run on any version of SQL?

> Find the name of every Texax-based
>   employeer, together with the name &
>   relationship of any dependents he/she
>   might have

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dependent_Name, Relationship
FROM EMPLOYEE LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT
WHERE Ssn = Essn
AND Adddress LIKE ‘%TX’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I'm aware. It needs to be

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dependent_Name, Relationship
FROM EMPLOYEE 
  LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT ON Ssn = Essn
WHERE Adddress LIKE '%TX'
```

Comment: I presumed as much. Chances are this will be on the exam as well, so I don't know what to write; his answer, which is wrong, but which he'll probably give full marks to, or the correct answer, which he probably thinks is incorrect.

Comment: Always right the correct answer -- this will serve you well in life.

Answer (score 3):

In standard SQL, an outer join (LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL) requires `ON...` or `USING...`. Standard SQL also requires single quotes--'%TX', not ‘%TX’. Standard SQL does *not* require you to spell column names correctly, but it's a good idea in general. ;-)

I wouldn't go as far as saying your SQL statement won't run on any SQL dbms. I've been doing this a long time. I've seen a lot of, ummmm, edge cases. (I'm pretty sure every SQL dbms doesn't conform to some part of every SQL standard.)

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dependent_Name, Relationship
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT ON Ssn = Essn 
WHERE Address LIKE '%TX';
```

You can also use the old, pre-ANSI syntax.

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dependent_Name, Relationship
FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPENDENT
WHERE Ssn = Essn
AND address LIKE '%TX';
```

To me, it looks like whoever is teaching you this stuff tried to update a pre-ANSI example by replacing the comma between `EMPLOYEE, DEPENDENT` with `LEFT JOIN`. While I might admire the economy of effort, I'd still have to give that person a failing grade.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, like this:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dependent_Name, Relationship
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN DEPENDENT on Ssn = Essn AND Adddress LIKE ‘%TX’
```

or

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dependent_Name, Relationship
FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPENDENT
WHERE Ssn = Essn AND Adddress LIKE ‘%TX’
```

Comment: Both of these answers are incorrect. The first one returns all Employees regardless of whether or not they live in `Tx`. The second one is an inner join so won't return Employees that live in `Tx` but have no dependants.

Comment: It does say `Adddress LIKE '%TX'` -- besides address being miss-spelled why won't that work @Martin?

Comment: I agree with the comment about the 2nd one, but I'm still wondering why you think the 1st one won't work, it does make an asumption that the address field is only in the employee table and not the dependent table.

Comment: @Hogan - Because it will return all `Employees` regardless of where they live. See http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/99060/ In the example data Bill Smith should not be returned as they do not live in `Tx` (Edit: Whoops linkl fixed now!)

Comment: Thanks @Martin can't argue with that example, I guess additional ANDs in the ON part can't work on the left side.

Comment: @Hogan - Well it works but it just answers a slightly different question in that it returns all Employees but only information about dependants of Texas based ones.

Comment: Ahh (light over head) it only applies the Texas to items that are joined and because it is a left join a number of items don't perform that join -- as an inner join it would work fine.